# Numerical range of subdirect sum (overlapping block matrices)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, numerical-linear-algebra, operator-algebras

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{q \times q}$ be nonsymmetric matrices.

If $p=q$, $A + B$ is the canonical sum.

If $p \ne q$ the following notions exist:

The direct sum of $A \oplus B$ is
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{A & 0 \\
         0 & B}
\end{align}

The subdirect sum $A \oplus_k B$, where $k$ is the level of overlap. For instance if $p=q=4$ and $k = 2$:
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} & 0& 0\\
         a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24}& 0& 0\\
         a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} + b_{11} & a_{34} + b_{12} &b_{13}&b_{14}\\
         a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} + b_{21} & a_{44} + b_{22} &b_{23}&b_{24}\\
         0 & 0 & b_{31} & b_{32} &b_{33}&b_{34} \\
         0 & 0 & b_{41} & b_{42} &b_{43}&b_{44}}
\end{align}

Define the numerical range or field of values as 
\begin{align}
W(A) = \left\{\frac{v^ T A v}{v^T v}, 0 \ne v \in \mathbb{C}^{p + q - 2k} \right\}
\end{align}
the following properties are known:
\begin{align}
W(A + B) \subseteq& W(A) + W(B) \\
W(A \oplus B) =& Co(W(A) \cup W(B))
\end{align}
where $Co()$ is the convex hull of a set.

**What can be said about $W(A \oplus_k B)$?**

Comment: Closely related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416236/overlapping-positive-definite-block-matrices). Shout out to @matthias-klupsch